# Populating a 2D list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to enter a 100 number square into a 2D list https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSFiO.png with each list containing 10 numbers 1-10,11-20,21-30 and so on. This is my code so far but when I run it in my editor it just keeps running and eventually crashes without printing anything. Please explain to me what I am doing wrong. Thanks

```
number_square=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
number_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for row in number_square:
  for number in number_list:
    number_square.append(number)
    number_list.remove(number)
    number_list.append(number+10)  
print(number_square)
```

Comment: `[list(range(10*(i-1) + 1, 10 * i +1)) for i in range(1,11)]`

Comment: can you elaborate on your comment? I can't work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you aren't accessing the content of neither `row` nor `number` in the `for` loops. Here is a suggestion:

```
number_square=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
number_list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
i = 0
for row in number_square:
 for i in range(len(number_list)):
   row.append(number_list[i])
   number_list[i] += 10       
print(number_square)
```

Note that the first loop is equivalent to `for each`. In this syntax, you can't alter the value of the item in a list. In the second loop, I put a "traditional" `for` loop with `range` to alter the values in `number_list`.

Answer (score 0):

There are many changes required in your code. Good effort from your side on trying the code. I have modified the code and probably you can get the logic from it.

```
number_square=[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]
number_list=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
for i in range(0,len(number_square)):
  for j in range(number_list[i]-9,number_list[i]+1):
    number_square[i].append(j)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problems:

1. Removing from `number_list` [while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6260089/4518341)
2. Appending to `number_square` instead of `row`

If I were you, I'd use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)s instead:

```
number_square = [list(range(i, i+10)) for i in range(1, 101, 10)]
```

*<sub>Due credit to [Onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu) for suggesting something similar in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808737/populating-a-2d-list#comment119855215_67808737)</sub>*